# QAbstractItemModel - lock data during removal?

Tags: qt, crash, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a QAbstractItemModel with a QSortFilterProxyModel on top of it. The data in this model is constantly updating, growing and shrinking so I have invalidateFilter on a timer that goes off every second so that the view reflects the changes in the data.

My problem is that every once in a while I hit a crash when filterAcceptsRow tries to access an index that was just removed. I am using beginRemoveRows/endRemoveRows and I was under the impression this would provide some sort of locking to prevent the data from being accessed during removal, but I can't find anything in the documentation that explicitly states that so I'm wondering if I'm mistaken about that.

So my questions are:

1) Does beginRemoveRows/endRemoveRows provide locking? and if not
2) What's the best practice for a situation like this to ensure data isn't removed out from under my filter routine?

I am using Qt/C++. Thanks.

Comment: Given that all of the operations happen on a single thread, there's no reason for locking: once the `beginRemoveRows` has emitted its signal, the removal code is running and no other code can access the model. Of course it all breaks down if you write pseudosynchronous code that can reenter the event loop while you're removing the items from the model - that would be a problem.

Comment: Do the crashes occur due to using the [internal pointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#internalPointer) to the actual data in `QModelIndex`? If so, there's a workaround: use [internal id](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#internalId) instead and access the data by that id so that you can fail nicely if no data for such id exists at the moment. This solution has a performance impact (search for data by id instead of just accessing it via pointer) but it can be relatively quick to do.

Comment: If you need to call invalidateFilter() just because data changed in the underlying model, then it is very likely that the underlying model does not correctly signal data change or that the proxy's `dynamiCSortFilter` is not turned on